# SwiftUI mailComposer View

Tags: swiftui, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Is there any way to enable attachment functionality on the SwiftUI MFMailComposeViewController? When displayed in my SwiftUI app, it accepts text but will not allow an image to be pasted in and does not show a button for adding an attachment. Is it possible to enable a fuller functionality more like the full standard mail composer you get with apple mail or Gmail? thanks

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import SwiftUI

struct MailView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @EnvironmentObject var theBody: GlobalData
    var imageData: NoteImageData


    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    @Binding var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?

    class Coordinator: NSObject, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
   
        @Binding var isShowing: Bool
        @Binding var result: Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?

        init(isShowing: Binding<Bool>,
             result: Binding<Result<MFMailComposeResult, Error>?>) {
            _isShowing = isShowing
            _result = result
        }

        func mailComposeController(_ controller: 
        MFMailComposeViewController,
                               didFinishWith result: 
        MFMailComposeResult,
                               error: Error?) {
        defer {
            isShowing = false
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            self.result = .failure(error!)
            return
        }
        if result == MFMailComposeResult(rawValue: 2){
            print("sent")
            playSound(sound: "mailSent", type: "mp3")
        }
        if result == MFMailComposeResult(rawValue: 0){
            print("----------------> cancelled <----------------")
            
           
        }
       
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //self.result = .success(result)
    }
}


func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(isShowing: $isShowing,
                       result: $result)
}

func makeUIViewController(context: 
    UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MailView>) -> 
    MFMailComposeViewController {
    let vc = MFMailComposeViewController()
    vc.mailComposeDelegate = context.coordinator

    vc.setSubject("")
    //vc.setMessageBody(imageData.description , isHTML: true)
    vc.setMessageBody( theBody.mailBody, isHTML: true)
    
    self.theBody.mailSuccess = true
    theBody.mailBody = "" //12/26
 
    return vc
}

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: 
    MFMailComposeViewController,
        context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MailView>) {
    print("==============> update UIviewController called")
 }
}
```

Comment: Would you show your code for MFMailComposeViewController representable?

Comment: Here is my MFMailComposeViewController code: